# Symfony2 entity is trying to use wrong database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an app that talks to two different databases. For one of my entities, `School`, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pressbox.schools' doesn't exist
```

That makes sense because there is no `pressbox.schools`. It's `fnt.schools`. It's trying to talk to the wrong database.

How do I tell my entity which mapping I want it to use? I would of course rather refer to the mappings than to the database names themselves, which can be different depending on the environment.

Comment: are you trying to link entities between two different databases?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, declare your connections in a config file (*config.yml* would be fine):

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: pressbox # change it as you wish
    connections:
      pressbox:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   pressbox
        user:     pressbox_usr
        password: pressbox_pwd
        charset:  UTF8
      fnt:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   fnt
        user:     fnt_usr
        password: fnt_pwd
        charset:  UTF8
```

Then declare the entity managers:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    default_entity_manager: pressbox
    entity_managers:
      pressbox:
        connection: web
      fnt:
        connection: fnt
```

Now, in a controller, you can tell Doctrine which entity manager to use by passing its name to `getEntityManager()`:

```
$fntEm = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('fnt');
```

Assuming the entity manager for the *fnt* table is called that same name.

Comment: I don't know - I'm not actually referring to the entity manager anywhere, so I don't know that this would really be relevant. It happens when I just do `$user->getSchool()` or something like that, which doesn't involve referring to the EM at all.

Comment: I thought you already configured your entity managers. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Updated. I'm not sure, but you might need to map an EM with a bundle like mentioned [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). Tell me if that's the case so I update the answer.

Comment: Hmm, now that I take a closer look, I realize that I was already doing everything suggested in your answer. If there's a way to tell a bundle to use a certain connection by default, I don't see it on that page you linked. If such a thing could be done, it seems like it would work, though.

Comment: This answer didn't fix my problem but I'm selecting it since it seems to be the best answer.

Comment: In case it might help someone, what fixed it for me was the key *connection* that i had forgotten for the entity_managers items...

Answer (score 0):

i think cross database relations are pretty complicated or you have to code by hand through some plugin.

i found this question about the same topic which might help you:

[Multiple database connection in Doctrine2 and Zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442521/multiple-database-connection-in-doctrine2-and-zend-framework)