# Doctrine not detecting schema changes with one entity manager and multiple databases

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Using Symfony-2.1 and Doctrine-2.3. I have multiple databases and need to do cross-database joins so I followed the suggestions in:

- [Multiple database connection in Doctrine2 and Zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442521/multiple-database-connection-in-doctrine2-and-zend-framework)
- [Using Relationships with Multiple Entity Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463517/using-relationships-with-multiple-entity-managers)

and set up multiple connections and one entity manager. Here is `app/config/config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: db1
        connections:
            db1:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     127.0.0.1
                dbname:   db1
            db2:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     127.0.0.1
                dbname:   db2
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    FirstBundle:
                        type:   annotation
                        dir:    Model
                        prefix: NoiseLabs\FirstBundle\Model
                    SecondBundle:
                        type:   annotation
                        dir:    Model
                        prefix: NoiseLabs\SecondBundle\Model
```

Entity class in `FirstBundle`:

```
namespace NoiseLabs\FirstBundle\Model;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="db1.table1")
 */
class FirstEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

Entity class in `SecondBundle`:

```
namespace NoiseLabs\SecondBundle\Model;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="db2.table2")
 */
class SecondEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NoiseLabs\FirstBundle\Model\FirstEntity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="firstId", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $first;
}
```

Now, the **problem is `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` only detects schema changes in (default connection) `db1.tables`**. If I set the default connection to `db2` it will only output sql related to `db2.tables`.

I've checked with `app/console doctrine:mapping:info` and all entity classes are being mapped.

Is this a limitation of Doctrine/Symfony or do I need to adjust my configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each entity manager can have only one connection. Split the default entity manager into two. `app/console doctrine:schema:update` takes an optional argument (`em`) to specify the entity manager in use. You'd have to run it twice:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql em="default"
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql em="my_second_em"
```

There's also a short article ([How to work with Multiple Entity Managers and Connections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)) in the Symfony2 cookbook that's worth reading.

Comment: In a single webapp I'm maintaining 10 Bundles and 7 databases. With this configuration for each EntityManager (aka database) I need to set /repeat the same mappings for all those 10 Bundles, otherwise a "*Class X was not found in the chain configured namespaces*" happens. Isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: @noisebleed:  I previously ran two queries for entities in two databases, and married them up in controller code using array_map or similar.  Mapping issue was a headache.  I ended up moving them to two schemas in the same database which works flawlessly.