# Cross database joins with Doctrine in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, multiple-databases

I was reading about cross database joins in Doctrine on their blog: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/cross-database-joins.html
The problem is that whenever table name contains a dot (used to specify the database), `doctrine:schema:update` outputs `Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.` The command basically just ignores entities whose table name contains a dot.

Comment: Here's a very similar question, but it has no right answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034943/doctrine-not-detecting-schema-changes-with-one-entity-manager-and-multiple-datab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal and it is a limitation of the ORM/DBAL.

The [`Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php) uses a [schema manager retrieved from your current connection](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php#L719-L744).

The `Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\AbstractSchemaManager` reads the tables [from the current connection's db](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.php#L820-L834), and not from all databases.

Therefore, you have to manually handle tables placed in different DBs, or use your own schema manager with your own `listTables` implementation.

Comment: If that's the case, I guess I'll just use multiple entity managers then.