# Symfony2 dynamic connection before check_login based on subdomain

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, multi-tenant, saas

I need to set a dynamic connection just before doing the login_check action. I know I can set the entity manager before get Repository but I'm using FOSUserBundle for login and this bundle always connects against default connection. I need to change connection dynamically before login_check based on subdomain. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple entity manager for FOSUserBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475180/multiple-entity-manager-for-fosuserbundle)

Answer (score 0):

Because of a lack of information I have to assume you are using doctrine2.

You can configure multiple entity managers

Bascially you configure both of them in your `config.yml` and tell doctrine upon retrieval of an entity manager which one you need.

Example:
`$this->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');`

Here is the article:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

And because you only need it on certain occasions I advise you to look up the topics [dependency injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#setting-up-the-container-with-configuration-files) and [controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html).

Comment: Thanks @marcel ! I know that way but I need to set the connection just before login_check. I'm using FOSUserBundle that always use  default entity manager to login

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475180/multiple-entity-manager-for-fosuserbundle?rq=1 or this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869233/fosuserbundle-with-multiple-entity-managers-symfony-2-set-up